# Luci unable to launch the requested CGI program: /www/cgi-bin/sample.cgi: Exec error

Tags: c++, cgi, openwrt, luci

I tried to execute a Cgi-Cpp program on a `uhttpd server` running on an `OpenWRT` install. The Cgi file is `/www/cgi-bin/sample.cgi` and has execute permissions too. I am trying to access this Cgi with HTML file. This is my `sample.cgi` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>  
#include <string>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 

#include <cgicc/CgiDefs.h> 
#include <cgicc/Cgicc.h> 
#include <cgicc/HTTPHTMLHeader.h> 
#include <cgicc/HTMLClasses.h>  

using namespace std;
using namespace cgicc;

int main () {
   Cgicc formData;

   cout << "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
   cout << "<html>\n";
   cout << "<head>\n";
   cout << "<title>Using GET and POST Methods</title>\n";
   cout << "</head>\n";
   cout << "<body>\n";

   form_iterator fi = formData.getElement("first_name");  

   if( !fi->isEmpty() && fi != (*formData).end()) {  
      cout << "First name: " << **fi << endl;  
   }else{
      cout << "No text entered for first name" << endl;  
   }
   cout << "</body>\n";
   cout << "</html>\n";

   return 0;
}
```

I get an error when I click the submit button in HTML:

```
unable to launch the requested CGI program: /www/cgi-bin/sample.cgi: Exec error
```

What am I missing? All permission are set there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are building the program correctly. First open a terminal window and cd to /www/cgi-bin. Now use

```
ls -l
```

to list the programs in the directory. You should have see your sample.cpp file there. If it is not there, move it there. If you no longer have a sample.cpp file, create a text file using the code you originally posted. You can do this with a text editor like nano.

```
nano sample.cpp
```

Type or paste in your source file. Then press ctrl-x to save and exit the program. Make sure you tell nano to save the program and not just exit.

Next delete your existing sample.cgi. Do not delete sample.cpp.

Use this command to build the source code (sample.cpp) into a binary executable file:

```
g++ sample.cpp -o sample.cgi
```

The "-o" is the letter "o", not the number "0". If building throws compilation errors, fix the errors and repeat until you successfully build the program. You will now have a binary file "sample.cgi".

Make sure "sample.cgi" is executable. If not, then make it executable with

```
sudo chmod a+x sample.cgi
```

Make sure you can first execute sample.cgi from the command line. If you cannot do this, then the server won't be able to either. Then type

```
"./sample.cgi".
```

You should see your html you sent from your app in your terminal window after you executed the app.

Let us know if you need further help.

Comment: I am getting `line 1: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")` when run `./sample.cgi` . Is it due to any compiling problem ?

Comment: I think so. How are you compiling the program? Using an IDE or from the command line? If from the command line, please post your commands to build the cgi script. Actually I suspect you are attempting to run the C++ source program as if it were a bash script. I will edit my original post to show you how to build the c++ source code.

Answer (score 1):

if you trying to make form then use shell script then c++. Here I show you how I created a file in which router can setup as in any mode like dhcp, pppoe or static.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'
echo '</head>'
echo '<br><h1><center>Welcome to Internet Service</center></h1>'

if [ -z "$QUERY_STRING" ]; then
    ssi=$(uci get wireless.@wifi-iface[1].ssid)
    key=$(uci get wireless.@wifi-iface[1].key)
    net=$(uci get network.wan.netmask)
    ipa=$(uci get network.wan.ipaddr)
    lip=$(uci -P /var/state get network.lan.ipaddr)
    ppu=$(uci get network.wan.username)
    ppp=$(uci get network.wan.password)
    ser=$(uci get network.wan.service)
    gat=$(uci get network.wan.gateway)
    rad=$(uci get network.wan.proto)
else
 # No looping this time, just extract the data you are looking for with sed:
 rad=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_a=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
 ssi=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_b=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
 key=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_c=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
 lip=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_j=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`     
 net=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_d=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
 ipa=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_e=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
 gat=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_f=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
 ppu=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_g=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
 ppp=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_h=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
 ser=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_i=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
fi

echo '<body>'
echo "<form method=GET action=\"${SCRIPT}\">"
if [ $rad = "dhcp" ]; then
echo "<center><input type="radio" name="val_a" value="dhcp" checked> DHCP"\
  '<input type="radio" name="val_a" value="static"> Static'\
  '<input type="radio" name="val_a" value="pppoe"> PPPoE</center><br>'
elif [ $rad = "static" ]; then
echo "<center><input type="radio" name="val_a" value="dhcp"> DHCP"\
    '<input type="radio" name="val_a" value="static" checked> Static'\
    '<input type="radio" name="val_a" value="pppoe"> PPPoE</center><br>'
else
echo "<center><input type="radio" name="val_a" value="dhcp"> DHCP"\
  '<input type="radio" name="val_a" value="static"> Static'\
  '<input type="radio" name="val_a" value="pppoe" checked> PPPoE</center>                    <br>'
fi
echo "<table nowrap align="center">"\
  '<tr><td>           SSID:</TD><TD><INPUT type="textarea" rows=1 name="val_b" size=12 value="'$ssi'" autofocus></td></tr>'\
  '<tr><td>  WiFi Password:</td><td><INPUT type="textarea" rows=1 name="val_c" size=12 value="'$key'" maxlength="16" minlength="8"></td></tr>'\
  '<table nowrap align="center">'\
  '<center>(Password should be of 8 characters)</center>'\
  '<tr><td><br> LAN IPaddress:</td><td><br><INPUT type="textarea" rows=1 name="val_j" size=12 value="'$lip'"></td></tr>'\
  '<table nowrap align="center" style="border:2px solid;" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5"><caption>Static Settings:-</caption>'\
  '<tr><td>    Subnet Mask:</td><td><INPUT type="textarea" rows=1 name="val_d" size=12 value="'$net'"></td></tr>'\
  '<tr><td>      IPaddress:</td><td><INPUT type="textarea" rows=1 name="val_e" size=12 value="'$ipa'"></td></tr>'\
  '<tr><td>Default Gateway:</td><td><INPUT type="textarea" rows=1 name="val_f" size=12 value="'$gat'"></td></tr><br>'\
  '<table nowrap align="center" style="border:2px solid;" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5"><caption>PPPoE Settings:-</caption>'\
  '<tr><td> PPPoE Username:</TD><TD><INPUT type="textarea" rows=1 name="val_g" size=12 value="'$ppu'"></td></tr>'\
  '<tr><td> PPPoE Password:</TD><TD><INPUT type="textarea" rows=1 name="val_h" size=12 value="'$ppp'"></td></tr>'\
  '<tr><td>   Service Name:</TD><TD><INPUT type="textarea" rows=1 name="val_i" size=12 value="'$ser'"></td></tr><br>'\
  '</table></table></table>'

echo '<center><br><input type="submit" style="width:80px;height:35px;" value="Save"></form>'

# Make sure we have been invoked properly.
if [ "$REQUEST_METHOD" != "GET" ]; then
    echo "<hr>Script Error:"\
         "<br>Usage error, cannot complete request, REQUEST_METHOD!=GET."\
         "<br>Check your FORM declaration and be sure to use METHOD=\"GET\".<hr>"
    exit 1
fi
# If no search arguments, exit gracefully now.
if [ -z "$QUERY_STRING" ]; then
    exit 0
else
 # No looping this time, just extract the data you are looking for with sed:
 rad=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_a=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
 ssi=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_b=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
 key=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_c=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
 lip=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_j=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`     
 net=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_d=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
 ipa=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_e=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
 gat=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_f=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
 ppu=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_g=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
 ppp=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_h=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
 ser=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_i=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`

 t1=$(ifdown wan)
 t2=$(uci set wireless.@wifi-iface[1].ssid=$ssi)
 t3=$(uci set wireless.@wifi-iface[1].encryption=psk2)
 t4=$(uci set wireless.@wifi-iface[1].key=$key)
 t5=$(uci commit wireless)
 t5=$(ifup wan)
 t6=$(wifi)
 t16=$(uci set network.lan.ipaddr=$lip)
 t7=$(uci set network.wan.proto=$rad)
 t8=$(uci set network.wan.username=$ppu)
 t9=$(uci set network.wan.password=$ppp)
 t10=$(uci set network.wan.service=$ser)
 t11=$(uci set network.wan.netmask=$net)
 t12=$(uci set network.wan.ipaddr=$ipa)
 t13=$(uci set network.wan.gateway=$gat)
 t14=$(uci commit network)
 t15=$(/etc/init.d/network restart)
fi

echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'
exit 0
```

Just call this file from html it will open in any browser.
Note:- Give 777 permission to this file and don't give any extension to this file. Just save it by giving its name.

Comment: If you found this useful, then tick as a right so other can refer this. Thank You